# Upon replacing brakes mechanic doesnt check bad wheel bearing

Tags: toyota, wheel-bearing, avalon

I took my car to a shop that my cousin has used for years. I asked please check my car for any other issues it may have as I drive alot. I knew I needed rear brakes and replace rotors. 500.00 dollars later I pickup my car and the next day I hear a rumbling noise in the rear. Bad wheel bearing hub. Another 500.00 pick up my car and within 3 min hear same sound. Now in front. shouldn't they have checked the rear while up on the lift? And what about the front? Should he offer to do it at his expense? As I initially asked them to full inspect my car? Avalon 2009

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I was also told by a worker that on the test drive they knew my front was bad but they didn't think id notice it..Mr.paulster, isn't that bad business? Isn't that a safety issue as well?

Comment: If they knew, then yah, bad business. Most shops have a policy where if the mechanic brings extra work into the business by realizing the vehicle they are working on needs something, the shop will give them a higher pay amount on the work they bring in ... It seems counterintuitive to me why someone there wouldn't have brought it up. It means more money all the way around and a happier customer. I wouldn't go back to this shop as they didn't earn my repeat business. I'd also let your friends know not to do business there, even if you were happy with the brake job. But that's me.

Comment: Thank you Paulster2...one final question. When I initially explained about my brakes, I said (very clearly) inspect my car and see if there's any other issues..he answered " have a seat we'll take care of everything"! Soooo , How do you miss rear bearing, then not proceed to inspect the others? I'm sorry to beat a dead horse but this place has great reviews and my cousins use them also for years..I'm just a ill bit (ok alot) in shock..1,000 for rear bearings, brakes, and rotors and now another 500? When this place could've/shouldve  fixed all the same day? Yea, he def. Didnt earn a dam thing

Comment: Even great places can have poor technicians. If you don't like the service you got, go to the service manager (or owner). They are the only ones who can rectify this for you. If it isn't worth the fight, move on.

Comment: It was the owner I spoke with...I guess I'll move on..2009 Avalon about how much to fix right side ball bearing? And thank you for taking out time to answer my questions..I sincerely mean this

Comment: Helping is what we do. Anytime you need help, please come back.

Comment: Mr. Paulster2, is 500.00 a lot to pay for a rear wheel bearing? And now another 500.00 for the front?

Comment: Seems like a lot of money to me, but I guess it depends on where you're at ... If you have further question specifically about cost, please visit us on [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you'd want to believe the mechanic will catch/fix everything, it really is beyond their control. They may or may not have checked it when up on the lift, but really, if that had found it, you'd still be paying for the work, so it isn't like they are charging you extra if you take it back there and they fix it for you. You might be able to ask for a discount, but I wouldn't expect they'd give you one. Your car's wheel bearings are worn out. They need replaced. It's only logical you should be paying for the work to happen, even as much as we'd like to think the mechanic is at fault.